# Android: how to load local javascript file to WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, android-jsinterface

I am trying to write a program which does a simple `toast`. When I tried adding the script within the `HTML`, it worked and am able to see the `toast`. But when I placed the same `script` code in separate file under `assert` folder(script.js), it fails to inject the `javascript`.

I am supporting API 15 and above.

Here is the code, where I trying to inject the `script`.

```
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewid);

    myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
            "<html>" +
            "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">" +
            "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
            "@font-face {\n" +
            "    font-family: MyFont;\n" +
            "    src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/myfont.ttf\")\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "body {\n" +
            "    font-family: MyFont;\n" +
            "    font-size: medium;\n" +
            "    text-align: justify;\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "</style>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body>" +
            "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Say hello\" onClick=\"showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')\" />" +
            "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"file:///android_asset/www/js/script.js\"/>" +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Here is my `javascript` code. (script.js)

```
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    };
```

Here is my `Javascript` Interface:

```
    protected class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /** Show a toast from the web page */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

How can I inject `javascript` file? Any help is appreciated.

My Project structure is like this:

```
    ---
      |
      ---- App
           |
           -----src
                |
                -----main
                     |
                     ------asserts
                     |     |
                     |     ------fonts
                     |     |
                     |     ------www
                     |     |     |
                     |     |     ------js
                     |     |           |
                     |     |           ------script.js
                     |
                     ------java
                     |
                     ------res
```

The cat log shows:

```
 E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught ReferenceError: showAndroidToast is not defined:13
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a WebView to display the data, you could upload it to a server or even Dropbox and then connect it with a url import?

Comment: That's the worst case... But I am trying to inject script, which works with internet connection.

Comment: Are you checking that the system is getting the script back and not returning it blank or that it cannot find it in the source folder

Comment: That's what, its not loading the script

Comment: Try putting it in your "fonts" folder and linking it like you did the font style file and if it works then you know that it is not finding your directory properly

Comment: Is there a www folder in your structure as the CSS files seam to not be in the www directory can you please post your folder structure as it appears in eclipse/android studio?

Comment: I added up my original project structure to the question. Please let me know what else you need.

Comment: Maybe try to change the file name and see if that helps, I have never had this problem before

Comment: OK, Any working example that you can share it with me. That would help me working on this further.

Comment: I am getting back following error:
E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught ReferenceError: showAndroidToast is not defined:13

Comment: I got this working from below URL. http://innovate-inspiron.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-load-local-javascript-in-android.html